# Regenerating /usr/share/locale/

Tags: linux, localization

Is there a way to regenerate deleted locale on /usr/share/locale without downloading the application again?

Answer (score 1):

No, only from the source code, so as I guess you don't have the source code, it's better you reinstall each packet.

On my distro for instance, the packages installing the mo are:

```
# rpm -qf /usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/*
apparmor-parser-2.3.1-11.13.1.i586
apparmor-utils-2.3.1-12.3.1.noarch
desktop-translations-11.2-11.16.1.noarch
libqdialogsolver1-1.3.0-2.11.i586
E16-20100214_r46173-7.1.i586
ecomp-20100214_r46173-8.1.i586
kupdateapplet-0.9.11-18.1.i586
libstorage-2.18.23-1.1.1.i586
libxine1-1.1.17-1.pm.25.3.i586
login-3.40-2.1.i586
pam-config-0.72-2.2.i586
sax2-gui-8.1-584.585.3.i586
scpm-1.1.7-6.1.i586
libzypp-6.21.2-1.1.1.i586
zypper-1.2.8-0.1.3.i586
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, localedef command is what you need.